# Using parent reference to call child methods

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, wildcard

I am writing a spawning system for my android game in Unity and for each type of enemy there is a different controller class, which by the way are not MonoBehaviours, these controller classes are controlled by the WaveController which is controlled by the Master enemy controller which is a MonoBehaviour (this doesn't make any difference, it's just easier to control the data flow).
Every controller inherits from the Controller abstract class, but also from the IController interface which takes in 5 generic arguments. You might already guessed it, but the data and functionality is split up since this was the whole spawning process of an enemy is a 5 step pipeline:

1. The Master controller determines the wave data
2. The Wave controller determines which controllers (since each enemy type has it's own controller) should be used and how
3. The controllers determine how and where enemies are spawned
4. Enemy objects are pulled from an object pool and spawned
5. Enemies are spawned with specific spawn data which is funneled through a scriptable object that is assigned to the Master controller

Without getting any more deeper into how this system works, my problem is that I have no way of updating a specific controllers data without separately referencing each type of controller data which would get really messy since like I said: the data referencing is inherited from the IController interface which requires 5 generic arguments :P

It's really a waste of my time to write the same code for each of controllers, and later even forget to add new controllers to the function.

PS all generic references are constrained by abstract classes.

I tried referencing each controller data separately, but this was too messy.

I also tried to abstract the ControllerData class, and having each controller have it's own ControllerData class that also inherits from an IControllerData interface for the generic referencing, but this didn't work since one of the 5 generic references also requires 2 generic references, BUT you can't cast nested generic arguments >:(

I just wish C# had wildcards like Java...

```
public class ObstacleControllerData<ObstacleType, ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject, SpawnMetricsScriptableObject, SpawnArguments>
        where ObstacleType : Obstacle
        where ObstacleScriptableObject : ObstacleSO
        where SpawnScriptableObject : SpawnSO
        where SpawnMetricsScriptableObject : SpawnMetricsSO<ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject>
        where SpawnArguments : SpawnArgs
{
    public float LastSpawnTime;
    public SpawnMetricsScriptableObject SpawnMetrics { get; private set; }
    public readonly ObstaclePool<ObstacleType, ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject, SpawnArguments> Pool;

    public ObstacleControllerData(SpawnMetricsScriptableObject spawn_metrics, ObstacleController controller)
    {
        LastSpawnTime = Time.time;
        SpawnMetrics = spawn_metrics;
        Pool = new(spawn_metrics.Data, controller, spawn_metrics.MaxActiveObstacles);
    }

    public void UpdateData(SpawnMetricsScriptableObject spawn_metrics)
    {
        Debug.Log("test update data");
    }
}

public abstract class ObstacleController
{
    public void TrySpawn()
    {
        if (CanSpawn())
            Spawn();
    }
    protected abstract void Spawn();
    protected abstract bool CanSpawn();
}

public class MissileController : ObstacleController, IObstacleController<Missile, MissileSO, MissileSpawnSO, MissileSpawnMetricsSO, MissileSpawnArgs>
{
    private ObstacleControllerData<Missile, MissileSO, MissileSpawnSO, MissileSpawnMetricsSO, MissileSpawnArgs> _data;
    public ObstacleControllerData<Missile, MissileSO, MissileSpawnSO, MissileSpawnMetricsSO, MissileSpawnArgs> ControllerData { get { return _data; } }

    private int _spawnRandomTarget;
    private List<int> _randomNumbers;

    protected override bool CanSpawn()
    {
        if (_data.Pool.ActiveObstaclesControlled == _data.SpawnMetrics.MaxActiveObstacles)
            return false;

        if (_data.LastSpawnTime > 0f && Time.time - _data.LastSpawnTime < _data.SpawnMetrics.Interval)
            return false;

        if (SpawnChanceSuccessful())
        {
            _data.LastSpawnTime = Time.time;
            return true;
        }
        else if (Time.time - _data.LastSpawnTime >= _data.SpawnMetrics.Interval)
        {
            _data.LastSpawnTime = Time.time;
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected override void Spawn()
    {
        MissileDirection direction = RandomDirection;
        MissileSpawnArgs spawn_args = new MissileSpawnArgs(RandomSpawnPosition(direction), direction);

        _data.Pool.SpawnObstacle(_data.SpawnMetrics.GetRandomSpawnData(), spawn_args);
    }

    public MissileController(MissileSpawnMetricsSO spawn_metrics)
    {
        _randomNumbers = new();
        _spawnRandomTarget = Random.Range(0, 100);

        _data = new(spawn_metrics, this);
    }
}

public interface IObstacleController<Obstacle, ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject, SpawnMetricsScriptableObject, SpawnArguments>
    where Obstacle : JumpMaster.Obstacles.Obstacle
    where ObstacleScriptableObject : ObstacleSO
    where SpawnScriptableObject : SpawnSO
    where SpawnMetricsScriptableObject : SpawnMetricsSO<ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject>
    where SpawnArguments : SpawnArgs
{
    public ObstacleControllerData<Obstacle, ObstacleScriptableObject, SpawnScriptableObject, SpawnMetricsScriptableObject, SpawnArguments> ControllerData { get; }
}
```

I need to call the UpdateData function from a reference of the ObstacleController

Comment: Give us code, not prose.

Comment: Without showing any code, all we can do is make guesses

Comment: Actually, this rant sounds like Generics is not the right tool, here ... but again: just a guess.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is rather a rant than a question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add some code

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually really simple, but the array of forums and videos were quite confusing to me for some reason. I just used the `dynamic` keyword like:

```
dynamic controller = controllers[0];
        controller.ControllerData.UpdateData(data);
```

To elaborate, the dynamic keyword is used to define an object of unknown type and property. What ever function you call, or property use, no matter if the the name syntax is correct there will be no compile error.
If there is an error in the code it wont be detected by the compiler, rather it will be noticed at runtime which is the only downside to using the dynamic keyword. Use it with care and only when you absolutely need it and know that there will be no error.
Since this is a Unity related question, the dynamic keyword works only if you set your projects .NET compatibility to 4.x